# Exception when consuming message from kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

In a Java project that is built by maven I'm trying to create a basic kafka (producer consumer) example.
when running [this code](http://ransilberman.wordpress.com/) I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: kafka/javaapi/producer/async/CallbackHandler : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.fetch(SimpleConsumer.scala:43)
    at com.taptica.avrotest.KafkaLocalBroker.main(KafkaLocalBroker.java:101)
```

I also tried running similar code against a real kafka server (with zoo-keeper) and again - message was sent successfully to kafka (I could also verify it in my kafka server) but when tried to consume it got the same mentioned exception.

Since I'm suspecting this is a matter of jar-versions mismatch here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.rtb</groupId>
    <artifactId>rtb-accumulation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <avro.version>1.7.5</avro.version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.2.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <jackson-version>1.9.13</jackson-version>
        <kafka-version>0.7.2-SNAPSHOT</kafka-version>
        <cglib-version>2.2.2</cglib-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>clojars.org</id>
            <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Kafka -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.clojars.jasonjckn</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.9.2</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Avro -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-ipc</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-mapred</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Misc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>r09</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade your java compiler.

Have a look at this link : [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0)

Comment: I'm using java 1.6 (this is my compiler version). So this means that the code i'm consuming is using a higher version (say 1.7)?

Comment: It means that one of the jars has been created using java 1.7 and therefore the java version you are using cannot process it correctly.